# Delete item with ajax from session in laravel 5.4, respond with 500 internal server error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session

I have this code to push products into array session in laravel 5.4

```
public function agregarACarrito(Request $request)
{
    $producto = new Producto();

    $producto = Producto::with('marca')
        ->where('id', '=', $request->parametros)
        ->get();

    $request->session()->push('session_products', $producto);
    return "Producto eliminado";

}
```

So, i want to delete an item using AJAX, this is my code right now:

```
public function borrarDeCarrito(Request $request){

  $productos = $request->session()->pull('session_products');

  foreach($productos as $key => $producto) {

      if ($request->parametros == $producto->id) {

        unset($productos[$key]);

        break;
      }
  }

  $request->session()->put('session_products', $productos);

 echo"¡Product removed!";

 }
```

I get a 500 internal server error and in the laravel error log i'm getting

'Exception' with message 'Property [id] does not exist on this collection 
 instance.

This is my ajax code

```
function borrarDeCarrito(id){


    var parametros=id;

            $.ajax({
            data:{parametros:parametros},
            url:'/borrarDeCarrito',
            type:'post',

            success:function(data){

                //console.log(data);

                alert(data);

            }
            });

}
```

¿what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the error message from the error log?

Comment: dd($request) what do you get??

Comment: check your logs on `/storage/logs/laravel.log` there should be a detailed information why you are getting error 500

Comment: im getting  'Exception' with message 'Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are pulling an unregistered index from your session.

> `$request->session()->push('session_products',$producto);`

In the code above, you push `session_products` to your session but you pull `$request->parametros` from your session on which you didn't register.

You can only pull `session_products` from `$request->session()`, and here's a quick fix

```
public function borrarDeCarrito(Request $request){
  $productos = $request->session()->pull('session_products');
  foreach($productos as $key => $producto) {
      if ($request->parametros == $producto->id) {
        unset($productos[$key]); 
        break;
      }
  }

  $request->session()->put('session_products', $productos);

}
```

UPDATE:

```
$producto = Producto::with('marca')
   ->where('id', '=', $request->parametros)
   ->get();
```

> 'Exception' with message 'Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

With the codes above you are trying to get 1 row by referencing its `id`, but you called `->get()` which is expected to return a multiple collection of Productos. 
And after you put that on your session, the structure becomes like this:

```
session_products = [
  0 => [0 => [name => 'productname', ...]]
]
```

Instead of:

```
session_products = [
  0 => [name => 'productname', ..]
]
```

You should use `->first()` when you only want to get a single row.
To fix it, simply:

```
$producto = Producto::where('id', '=', $request->parametros)
   ->with('marca')
   ->first();
```

Comment: The problem persist, i get the same error in the console with this code =(

Comment: @rodrigo1990 oh, I had a typo. I updated my answer. Can you try again?

Comment: Ok, i probed this, and it is working, the product it's been deleted from the session, but, the AJAX success function doesn't work.
The console throws 500 server error.
So, if i return a message from the controller for example "return: '¡Product removed!', the AJAX success function doesn't work.

Comment: i updated the original question, and put the ajax code

Comment: Try `echo '¡Product removed!';`, instead of `return '¡Product removed!';`.

Comment: can you include the code where exactly you put the return message in your controller?